# Intuitive explanation of Ward's method

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, euclidean, ward

I got this explanation of the Ward's method of hierarchical clustering from Malhotra et. al (2017), and I don't really get what it means:

> Ward’s procedure is a variance method which attempts to generate clusters to minimise the within-cluster variance. For each cluster,
> the means for all the variables are computed. Next, for each object,
> the squared Euclidean distance to the cluster means is calculated.
> These distances are summed for all the objects. At each stage, the two
> clusters with the smallest increase in the overall sum of squares
> within cluster distances are combined.

I understand that if we have $n$ objects, then we start off with $n$ clusters. From there, they say that the means for all the variables is computed (so we got $p$ x $n$ means). And then they say that the distance from each object to to the 'cluster means' is calculated. This is where I get confused - the object means are the cluster means (at stage 1), so what distance is there to calculate?

Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, at the first stage, where each point $x\in X$ in your dataset $X$ is a cluster, all the distances to the cluster means are zero, so the overall sum of squared within-cluster distances is zero. So now the task is to find the two points which to combine first, such that afterward the overall sum of squared within-cluster distances is the least increased, i.e. you have to find, at stage two, the two points:
$$
(x_k, x_l) = argmin_{(x_r, x_s)\in X^2} \{\|x_r - x_s\|\}.
$$
You iterate as described, but in those later stages, the cluster centers are not necessarily anymore the points themselves.

Comment: Ah that's exactly what I thought. Just to confirm, once we've clustered some points, we then calculate the distance between other objects and its CENTROID right?

Comment: Also, isn't it funny how they then add "These distances are summed for all the objects"? I wonder what that means

Comment: @Academic005 At each stage, the $N$ points are grouped in clusters. Each of those clusters has a mean. You compute for each point the squared distance to the mean of the cluster that point is contained in. Those are $N$ squared distances that you sum up. That's what they refer to when saying: "These distances are summed for all the objects".